# How can I edit crontabs in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cron

If I try to use Visual Studio Code (on macOS 10.15) to edit my crontab, it opens an empty file without the contents of my crontab.

```
$ VISUAL='code' crontab -e
crontab: no changes made to crontab
```

I didn't actually expect this to work (without `-w`) but include it for completeness.  But when I add the `-w` it still fails.

```
$ VISUAL="code -w" crontab -e
crontab: code -w: No such file or directory
crontab: "code -w" exited with status 1
```

It occurred to me that there may be some weirdness with quoting, but neither single quotes nor the following fixed anything:

```
$ function codew() {
function> code -w "$1"
function> }
$ export VISUAL='codew'
$ crontab -e
```

The problem seems to be that the crontab's tempfile is not actually present.  But how do I solve this?  How can I use VS Code to edit crontabs?

Comment: It may be helpful to include what OS you're running on (seems to be mac or linux?)

Answer (score 14):

1. Create a file `touch ~/code-wait.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
OPTS=""
if [[ "$1" == /tmp/* ]]; then
    OPTS="-w"
fi

/usr/local/bin/code ${OPTS:-} -a "$@"
```

2. Make this file executable:

```sh
chmod 755 ~/code-wait.sh
```

3. Add to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc`:

```sh
export VISUAL=~/code-wait.sh
export EDITOR=~/code-wait.sh
```

4. Run command:

```sh
EDITOR='code' crontab -e
```

Comment: P.S: echo $SHELL - helps to check what shell you're using

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: It just helps you to use your vscode editor for editing a cron-job file

Comment: But um... what does it do? it looks like it gets the other command line arguments and appends them somehow to the call to open vscode?

Comment: Also, i use remotevscode # https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafaelmaiolla.remote-vscode#review-details

Not working :-(

Comment: @fotoflo try to update PATH. CMD+shift+P, input "path", and click on the first finding

Comment: @DmitryGrinko `$SHELL` doesn't tell you the shell you're currently using.  If I'm not mistaken, it tells you your default shell, which *might* be your current shell.  I use zsh, but if I enter bash and type `echo $SHELL`, I still see `/bin/zsh`.

Comment: @iconoclast Ok, here are some additional commands you can use:  `cat /etc/shells` to get list of your shells. `ps -p $$` - to get your default shell.

Comment: FYI: Doesn't work with `sudo crontab -e`; throws unknown `FileSystemError`. Per the `renderer` log: `[File Watcher (node.js)] Failed to watch /private/tmp/crontab.foobar for changes using fs.watch() (Error: EACCES: permission denied, watch '/private/tmp/crontab.foobar')`

Comment: @IllyaMoskvin adjusting the chmod permissions step may allow sudo to work

Comment: I had to use `/opt/homebrew/bin/code` instead of `/usr/local/bin/code`. I am on macOS Sonoma and VSCode is installed with Homebrew. You can do `which code` in order to get the path to `code` executable.

Answer (score 4):

here the setting works for me.

.bashrc

```sh
## vscode
export VISUAL=/path/to/code-wait.sh
export EDITOR=/path/to/code-wait.sh
```

code-wait.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
code -w $*
```

Comment: This comment works for git as well, thanks for sharing!

Comment: The most elegant answer is always the one that is the most simple. This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

That is quite a complex issue because there is no way to detect which tool calls the preferred editor. The TTY is the same and no environment variables can help.

Still, I was able to come up with a solution that enables the foreground mode (wait) for temporary files. IMHO, most if not all tools that use external editors and are waiting for them to save the file do use temporary files.

Full script is at https://github.com/ssbarnea/harem/blob/master/bin/edit but I will include here the main snippet:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
OPTS=""
if [[ "$1" == /tmp/* ]]; then
    OPTS="-w"
fi

/usr/local/bin/code ${OPTS:-} -a "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks people, works for me, even on a remote. though the path won't be consistent. I found that simply removing the path does work.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
OPTS=""
if [[ "$1" == /tmp/* ]]; then
    OPTS="-w"
fi

code ${OPTS:-} -a "$@"
```